# accessing a relation in the initializer, mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am migrating a project from MongoMapper to Mongoid. I have a two models, `Graph` and `Point` with a referenced 1-N relation, so a point `belongs_to :graph`, and each graph `has_many :points`. I have overridden the initializer in the Point model as I need to reference some state from the graph instance that the point belongs to in order to correctly initialize the point.

It seems, however, that the relation isn't initialized even after calling `super` in the initializer. How can I correctly set up the state of Points?

Here's a simplified version of my two classes and the initializer:

```
class Graph
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :points,  dependent: :delete

  field :type,       type: String
  field :timezone,   type: String

  # ...etc...
end

class Point
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :graph

  field :date,    type: Date
  field :value,   type: Float
  field :urtext,  type: String  # as originally entered by user
  field :nextday, type: Date

  attr_accessible :urtext

  validates :value, presence: true
  validates :date,  presence: true

  def initialize(params, options={})
    super(params, options)
    parse_urtext
  end

  def parse_urtext(ur)
    # for the sake of argument, imagine this is doing some critical calculation
    # that requires info derived from current state of the graph at creation
    # and which is related to parsing the urtext

    self.date, self.value = urtext.split(",")
    self.nextday = Time.use_zone(self.graph.timezone){ Time.zone.now.to_date + 1 }
  end
end
```

When I try to create a new point associated with the graph, I'm getting a nil error from the initializer.

```
# in a console:
> g = Graph.first
> p = g.points.build( urtext: "2015-11-30,1" )
  NoMethodError: undefined method `timezone' for nil:NilClass
      from /rails_root/app/models/point.rb:34:in `parse_urtext'
      from /rails_root/app/models/point.rb:22:in `initialize'
      from /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mongoid-3.1.7/lib/mongoid/factory.rb:23:in `new'
      ...
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working? I can write a build_point method on the Graph model and always create Points that way, but then I lose the benefit of following Rails conventions. Callbacks don't seem to get me the behavior I want either. (Validations are the first thing run, and I want to finish initializing the state before the validations).

Rails 3.2.22, Mongoid 3.1.7

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong. Overriding `initialize` when using an O[RD]M is almost always a bad idea.

A more common approach would be to use the standard lifecycle hooks to parse things. For example, you could use `before_validation`:

```
class Point
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :graph

  field :date,    type: Date
  field :value,   type: Float
  field :urtext,  type: String
  field :nextday, type: Date

  before_validation :parse_urtext, :if => :urtext_changed?

  validates :value, presence: true
  validates :date,  presence: true

private

  def parse_urtext
    self.date, self.value = self.urtext.split(",")
    self.nextday = Time.use_zone(self.graph.timezone){ Time.zone.now.to_date + 1 }
  end

end
```

In some cases you could override the `urtext` mutator method:

```
def urtext=(v)
  ...
end
```

but that won't work here. Saying `g.points.build( urtext: "2015-11-30,1" )` will call `#urtext=` but not necessarily before `#graph_id=` is called so you could (and actually will in this case) have `self.graph.nil?` when `#urtext=` is called during `g.points.build(...)`.

I tend to use `before_validation` hooks for this sort of thing and then `validates` hooks to make sure the `before_validation` calls did the right things.

Comment: I started out trying to use the lifecycle callbacks, but had essentially a race condition because I put my code in an after_create callback reasoning that the graph/relation state would hopefully be initialized by then. I never made it to the creation callbacks, because the goal wasn't valid, and the goal wasn't valid because I never made it all the way through creation... I'll have to think it through a bit more to see if I can use before_validation hooks to do this.